# 4th level domain redirect to domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know how to redirect from 3rd level domain like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(something)\.domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.something.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Is there a way to perform same thing to redirect **something.name.domain.com** to **something.name**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite rules are much like (driven by) regular expressions. From what I'm reading, you can use `RewriteCond` backreferences:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1
```